# Why processor time suddenly become long?

Tags: python, pandas, processor

I face a phenomenon that processor time suddenly becomes long from a particular point, while executing a program that read and process some large data.

The following is detailed.

The directory constitution of target data is day/hour/minute/, and approximately 700 data files(hdf5) are stored in each minute directory. For example, 01/23/52/file1.h5. The size of each h5 file is about 200kB. Therefore, the total size of data is 140MB per minute, 8.4GB per hour, and 200GB per day. My program read h5 files and store data with pandas for every one minute and handle it for every one hour.

The following codes are extracts from my program.

```
import pandas as pd
import time
...
hours=["00","01",......,"23"]
minutes=["00","01",.....,"59"]
...
f=open("log.txt","w")
for thishour in hours:
    onehourdata=pd.DataFrame()
    for thisminute in minutes:
        filepath=pathtodata+"/"+thishour+"/"+thisminute+"/"
        filelist=os.listdir(filepath)
        onemindata=pd.DataFrame()
        dflist=[]
        ptime1=time.clock()
        for thisfile in filelist:
            filename=filepath+thisfile
            store=pd.HDFStore(filename)
            newdata=store["table"]
            store.close()
            dflist.append(newdata)
        ptime2=time.clock()
        f.write("hour:{0} min:{1} p2-p1:{2}".format(thishour,thisminute,ptime2-ptime1))

        onemindata=pd.concat(dflist)
        onehourdata=pd.concat([onehourdata,onemindata])
    onehourdata=onehourdata.groupby([column1,column2,column3],as_index=False).sum()
...
...
```

I executed the program and get following log.txt

```
hour:00 min:00 p2-p1:15.01
...
...
...
hour:20 min:50 p2-p1:17.02
hour:20 min:51 p2-p1:14.33
hour:20 min:52 p2-p1:40.25
hour:20 min:53 p2-p1:42.52
...
...
hour:22 min:30 p2-p1:41.62
...
...
hour:23 min:59 p2-p1:50.21
```

When I execute the program for the data of the same day, processor time becomes long from the same point. Moreover, the result was the same although I performed generating a grandchild process and kill the parent process with a fork. When investigated using line　profiler, it turned out that the line of newdata=store["table"] has taken time most.

The environment is Ubuntu Server 13.04-x86_64 and memory size is 512GB.

Why processor time suddenly become long?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "become long"?

Comment: FYI, this is a very inefficient way of storing your data. straightforward to simply store all of the data for an hour in a single HDFStore (or by group if you really want), with a table, see: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#table-format

Comment: >user2357112 Thank you for your comment. It is that the processor time per one minute becomes long in log.txt. I use such an expression because I couldn't understand a cause.

Comment: >Jeff Thank you for your comment. Because I cannot access data for the year-end and New Year holidays, I'm going to try next year. Is the technique to use table usable when there is 700 hdf5 file per one minute(ex. 01/01/01/file[1-700].h5)? I thought that I need to store by 1 file after all.